# Segmentaion fault in C++ when doing matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, c, matrix

I have a program below which is supposed to analyze the timing of the  matrix multiplication according to different indexing.. But some of the functions are giving segmentation fault, two of which are matmul_kji(C,A,B) and  matmul_jki(C,A,B). Could somebody could explain to me what I am doing wrong and possible improvements. This code should check timing of matrixes from (1000*1000) to (10000*10000).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>  

using namespace std;
# define MATSIZE 1000


double get_wall_time(){
    struct timeval time;
    if (gettimeofday(&time,NULL)){
        //  Handle error
        return 0;
    }
    return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec * .000001;
}
double get_cpu_time(){
    return (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}  

void init_mat ( double M[MATSIZE][MATSIZE])
{
int i, j;
for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
M[i][j] = sin(double(i));
}
}
}

void matmul_ijk ( double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],
double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE], double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE]) //1
{
int i, j, k;        
double aux;

double cpu0 = get_cpu_time();
for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
aux = 0;
for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];
}
C[i][j] += aux;
}
}
double cpu1 = get_cpu_time();
cout << "CPU Time Of IKJ Ordering = "<< cpu1-cpu0<<endl;
}                      

void matmul_ikj ( double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],
double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE], double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE]) //2
{
int i, j, k;        
double aux;

double cpu0 = get_cpu_time();
for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
aux = 0;
for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];
}
C[i][j] += aux;
}
}
double cpu1 = get_cpu_time();
cout << "CPU Time Of IKJ Ordering = "<< cpu1-cpu0<<endl;
}         

void matmul_kij ( double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],
double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE], double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE])  //3
{
int i, j, k;        
double aux;

double cpu0 = get_cpu_time();
for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
aux = 0;
for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];
}
C[i][j] += aux;
}
}
double cpu1 = get_cpu_time();
cout << "CPU Time of KIJ ordering = "<< cpu1-cpu0<<endl;
}                      

void matmul_kji( double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],
double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE], double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE]) //4
{
int i, j, k;        
double aux;

double cpu0 = get_cpu_time();
for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
aux = 0;
for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];
}
C[i][j] += aux;
}
}
double cpu1 = get_cpu_time();
cout << "CPU Time Of IKJ Ordering = "<< cpu1-cpu0<<endl;
}                      


void matmul_jik( double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],
double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE], double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE])   //5
{
int i, j, k;        
double aux;

double cpu0 = get_cpu_time();
for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
aux = 0;
for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];
}
C[i][j] += aux;
}
}
double cpu1 = get_cpu_time();
cout << "CPU Time Of KJI Ordering = "<< cpu1-cpu0<<endl;
}      

void matmul_jki ( double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],
double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE], double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE])   //6
{
int i, j, k;        
double aux;

double cpu0 = get_cpu_time();
for (j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
for (k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
aux = 0;
for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];
}
C[i][j] += aux;
}
}
double cpu1 = get_cpu_time();
cout << "CPU Time Of JKI Ordering = "<< cpu1-cpu0<<endl;
}                   

/*void matmul_ikj( double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE],              
double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE], double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE])
{
int i, j, k;        
double aux;

double cpu0  = get_cpu_time();

for (i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
for (k=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
aux = 0;
for (j=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
aux += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
}
C[i][j] += aux;
}
}
double cpu1  = get_cpu_time();
cout << "CPU Time  = " << cpu1  - cpu0  << endl;
} */         

int main ()
{
static double A[MATSIZE][MATSIZE];
static double B[MATSIZE][MATSIZE];
static double C[MATSIZE][MATSIZE]= {{0}};

init_mat (A);
init_mat (B);

//matmul_ijk(C,A,B);
//matmul_ikj(C,A,B);  
//matmul_kij(C,A,B);
matmul_kji(C,A,B);      // Gives a segmentation error
//matmul_jik(C,A,B);
matmul_jki(C,A,B);    // Gives a segmentation error

/*for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < 10; j++){
        cout << C[i][j]<<"  ";
    }
    cout <<endl; } */      

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
C[i][j] += aux; // Inside matmul_kji
```

This is executed inside two nested loops with variables `j` and `k`, not `i` and `j`, so it should be

```
C[j][k] = aux;
```

Note that you need to replace `+=` with `=`, because all the additions have been done by the third nested loop.

Also note that the compiler can help you avoid problems like this if you use the modern <sup>*</sup> way of defining loop variables: rather than defining them upfront, define them inside the loop header, like this:

```
for (int k=0; k<MATSIZE; k++) {
    for (int j=0; j<MATSIZE; j++) {
        double aux = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<MATSIZE; i++) {
            aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] += aux; // <<== Compile error!
    }
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> "Modern" is very relative: this way of declaring loop variables has been around since mid-eighties, making it quite old.

Comment: Might want to note also that `aux += A[i][k] *B[k][j];` is in any case probably wrong - the `B[k][j]` should depend on `i`, the innermost loop variable.  It's not 100% clear what *is* correct, given that I'm not sure whether the first or second index should represent rows/columns in his representation nor which of `A` or `B` is the left resp. right matrix in the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a segmentation fault for the two cases that don't set `i` in the outer loop, due to

```
C[i][j] += aux;
```